# ACF - display div based on select value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to trigger variable content based on the value set on a select custom field on a page. If the option selected is "Header standard" then display a div.

The code I'm using is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php $featured_post = get_field('test_header_field'); ?>

<?php if(the_field('test_header_field', $featured_post) == "Header Standard"): ?>
    <div>The Content if test_header_field is equal to Header Standard.</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your code to something like below:

```
<?php
// grab acf field
$featured_post = get_field('test_header_field');

// set bool based on featured_post text
$is_header_standard = $featured_post === "Header Standard";
?>

<?php 
// conditionally display based on previously set bool
if ($is_header_standard) : ?>
    <div>The Content if test_header_field is equal to Header Standard.</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your php to this

```
<?php if( $featured_post = "Header Standard") : ?>
    <div...
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: think this answer is missing `==` or better `===` in place of the `=`.